# How do I convert a 4 channel stereo file to mono in Python

Tags: audio, pydub

How do I convert a 4 channel stereo file to mono in Python, preferably using pydub? Thanks in advance

Comment: just a note: Four channels is *not* stereo - stereo is two channels (left and right). The term for 4-channel audio is "quadrophonic"

Answer (score 5):

From the pydub documentation, I suppose you can try something like that:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment 

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("example.wav") #read wav
song.export("out.wav", parameters=["-ac", "1"])             # export wav (1 channel)
```

As I understand the documentation, the values of "parameters" is based on the ffmpeg documentation ([audio options](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options)). So you can use all parameters from ffmpeg. Here, I just set the number of audio channels to 1.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Patrice answer, as per [this discussion](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/232) on `github` `pydub` repo, export returns without executing `ffmpeg` with parameters if format is `wav`.

You may need to modify `pydub.AudioSegment` as below in order for `ffmpeg` to actually execute with optional parameters provided in export.

Changing line 600

```
if format == "wav":
    data = out_f
else:
    data = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="wb", delete=False)
```

to:

```
if format == "wav" and parameters is None:
        data = out_f
    else:
        data = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="wb", delete=False)
```

And line 616:

```
 if format == 'wav':
            return out_f
```

to:

```
 if format == 'wav' and parameters is None:
            return out_f
```

Then `ffmpeg` accepts parameters and processes accordingly .

I don't have a  "quadrophonic" audio sample to test this "theory", if you can upload to your `github` issue tracker ,  above can be tested.
Let me know.